# How to transform Go string literal code to its value?

Tags: string, go, string-literals

I'm walking around syntax tree in Go, trying to find all calls to some particular function and then get its string argument (it's a file name, and should be string literal, not any other identifier). I'm succeeded with this, and now I have `ast.BasicLit` node with `Kind == token.STRING`, but its value is Go code, not a value of the string that it should have.

I found question that answers how to do reverse transformation - from string to go code it represents: [golang: given a string, output an equivalent golang string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779371/golang-given-a-string-output-an-equivalent-golang-string-literal)

But I want the opposite - something like eval function (but just for Go string literals).

Comment: Are you looking for [`strconv.Unquote()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote)? Possible duplicate of [How to convert escape characters in HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36528575/how-to-convert-escape-characters-in-html-tags/36529158#36529158)

Comment: @icza Yes, `strconv.Unquote()` seems to do the job (except I don't want it to touch anything it thinks is HTML, because it is filename written as go string). But I checked with "&nbsp;hello.txt" and it worked fine. You could post your answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`strconv.Unquote()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote) to do the conversion (unquoting).

One thing you should be aware of is that `strconv.Unquote()` can only unquote strings that are in quotes (e.g. start and end with a quote char `"` or a back quote char `` ` ``),  so you have to manually append that if it's not in quotes.

Example:

```
fmt.Println(strconv.Unquote("Hi"))       // Error: invalid syntax
fmt.Println(strconv.Unquote(`Hi`))       // Error: invalid syntax
fmt.Println(strconv.Unquote(`"Hi"`))     // Prints "Hi"
fmt.Println(strconv.Unquote(`"Hi\x21"`)) // Prints "Hi!"

// This will print 2 lines:
fmt.Println(strconv.Unquote(`"First line\nSecondline"`))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SudNBW0NjQn)):

```
 invalid syntax
 invalid syntax
Hi <nil>
Hi! <nil>
First line
Secondline <nil>
```